# Class destruction in Java

Tags: java, jvm

I know that the garbage collector of Java can tidy up the dead class instances, but how about the class itself? I mean the static fields of a class?

I know that during the class initialization, static fields get initialized, but after this, is there a way to delete them?

Comment: Do you mean the values that were assigned to the static fields, or the static fields (primitives, refereneces) themselves?

Comment: @RealSkeptic I mean the static fields themselves.

Answer (score 4):

A `Class` can be GCd if its `ClassLoader` is GCd.

After that you will have to reload the class, at which point the static fields will be re-initialized.

This can be easily tested by loading a class with for example a `URLClassloader`.

Comment: Note that from jdk 7+ even String literals defined inside a class (which go into the String constants pool) can get GCed if classloader of that class is GCed.

Comment: Test: `static final Object x = new Object() {{ System.out.println("Good Morning, Groundhog" }};`